# I want to remove previous url from my local host and replace it with the custom url given

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have implemented search bar in my application and I am using autocomplete plugin for that. On the select event of that after selecting an item from list I am redirecting it to another page with the custom Url I have provided But it is not working on another page because the custon url is getting appeneded with the url I have already given. So kindly give me solution for that.

I have tried replacing url with window.locarion.replace("url") but it is not helping

```
$("#txtsearch").autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Search", "Product")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    search: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {

                response($.map(data, function (item) {

                        return {
                            label: item.ModelName,
                            value: item.ModelName,
                            type:item.ID
                        };

                    }))

                }
            })
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            debugger;
           //var  url = 'Product/Review/' + ui.item.value + '-' + ui.item.type
            window.location.replace('Product/Review/'+ ui.item.value +'-' +  ui.item.type);
           // window.location.href = url;
           //window.location.href = ('Product/Review/' + ui.item.value + '-' + ui.item.type);

        }


    });
```

I want some code so that on select event previous url will get removed and I will be able to redirect the user to the custom url I have given in the select event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a forwarding slash at the starting, like this:

```
window.location.replace('/Product/Review/'+ ui.item.value +'-' +  ui.item.type);
```